# No circle around あ on main page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The circle around the logo is missing on the main page. I'm using firefox 26.0 on Fedora 18.

[image: japanese language]

EDIT: The circle appears now, but the 'N' got messed up:

[image: japanese language]

Comment: That's interesting!  It shows up for me regardless of which browser I use.

Comment: Ok, I think I see where the issue is. Fix should be released in ~24 hours. I would appreciate feedback after that as I'm not able to test it on Fedora :(

Comment: the problem may be due to background image ("img/sprites.svg?v=eb8baaee1183"). Because ("img/sprites.png?v=20941b0a3693") works fine.

Comment: I can confirm that it's showing up as **JAPA\ESE LA\GUAGE** for me as well (Debian testing, Firefox 45 and Chromium 50).

Comment: can anyone confirmed that "N" issue has been fixed?

Comment: @Paweł yup looks perfect! thanks

Comment: I still see **JAPA\ESE LA\GUAGE** when viewed in Chrome on Windows 7.  Firefox shows the capital **N** correctly. ... ... and now, super bizarrely, the **N** is appearing correctly in Chrome too -- but only after I launched Firefox and browsed to the site.  Maybe there's a Windows library that's behaving strangely?

Comment: The N looks fine for me in Chrome on Windows 7 now.  (And in everything else, too.)